# Manipulate date with symfony 1.4

Tags: php, date, symfony1

I would like to know if a class exists to manipulate date with symfony 1.4

I search a class like Calandar in Java where you can manipulate date with method like "add" to add x days to a date.

I found `sfDatePlugin` but it seems to work only symfony 1.2

Do you know a class like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in PHP [DateTime](https://www.php.net/datetime) class and the [modify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method:

```
$dt = new DateTime(); //will be now
$dt->modify('+3 days');
$dt->format('m/d/Y'); //takes the same params as date()
```